# Using XPath to select the href attribute of the following-sibling

Tags: html, google-chrome, xpath, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape the following site: http://www.hudson211.org/zf/profile/service/id/659837

I am trying to select the href next to the "web address" text. The following xpath selector gets the tag I am after:

```
$x("//th[contains(text(), 'Web Address')]/following-sibling::td/a")
```

returns

```
<a href="http://www.co.sullivan.ny.us">www.co.sullivan.ny.us</a>
```

However, when I specifically try to extract the href using @href, the return value is an empty array:

```
$x("//th[contains(text(), 'Web Address')]/following-sibling::td/a/@href")
```

returns `[]`

This is the html of the row I am looking at:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td class="profile_view_left"></td>
    <th align="left" class="profile_view_center">Web Address</th>
    <td class="profile_view_right">
      <ahref="http://www.co.sullivan.ny.us">www.co.sullivan.ny.us</a>                         </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using Google Chrome console because of that `$x()` function. Your xpath which selects `@href` attribute **actually worked**, as I tested in my Chrome, only the result is not displayed in the console like when you selected an element -for a reason that I'm not quite sure at the moment- :

```
>var result = $x("//th[contains(text(), 'Web Address')]/following-sibling::td/a/@href")
undefined
>result[0].value
"http://www.co.sullivan.ny.us"
```

see that using the exact same expression, variable `result` contains the expected url value. If your intention is simply to display single `href` value in the console without further processing, this will do :

```
>$x("//th[contains(text(), 'Web Address')]/following-sibling::td/a/@href")[0].value
"http://www.co.sullivan.ny.us"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling on the same issue. My trouble was to extract href from `<a href="/topic/19778287" name="topic">实体</a>`. However using `//a[@name = "topic"]/@href` the console displays empty list. Then I used your approach and realize it **actually returns the correct list**. Maybe a bug in Chrome -_-